# Problem replacing content with \r or \n with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Sorry for my english, I'm french aha !

I'm currently stucked on a problem with my script.
I'm trying to create conditional tags in my GDoc templates : the content in the tag will be displayed in the body of my doc if the condition is verified.
Example :

`<<IF : (true)>>hello World !<<ENDIF>>`

"Hello world !" will be displayed because the condition is verified.

I'm using this regex to find my tags :
`var regex = new RegExp(/<<IF : \(([^\)]*)\)>>(?!<<IF)+(.*?)<<ENDIF>>/gs); I verify the condition and I use body.replaceText("<<IF : (true)>>hello World !<<ENDIF>>","hello World")`
to delete the tag to keep only the text I want in my final doc.

I have few problems :
My code work when the content of the text I want to display doesn't contain `\n` or `\r` and when my tag is on one only line.

Indeed : these two examples won't work :

1)
<<IF : (true)>>hello

World !<>

2)
`<<IF : (true)>>

hello World !

<>

Do you know how I can use replaceText in appscript to replace text which contains `\r` ?
It will help me a lot to finish my project...

Hope you'll can help me !
Thanks !

Comment: While it may be true that you don't know how to use replace text in google apps script.  Our assumption is that you can read the documentation and make a better attempt at a first code.  Note this is no endif in Google Apps Script.  [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/54630)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
body.replaceText(".*<<IF : \\(true\\)>>(.*)<<ENDIF>>.*", "hello World");
```

**Example:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

- [replaceText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement)
- [re2](https://github.com/google/re2)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers and comments but it not help because it's not about my problem aha !
My problem is to replace content which contains \r and \n.
Indeed, my regex is already working, but I can't use the result of it in body.replace because of the char \r or \n !